# Why can't I hit my nested route? ReactRouter4

Tags: react-router-v4

I am trying to hit a nested Route, but for some reason it is not hitting the `Component`'s render function.  Here is my route file:

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/financefe" render={() => (
    <Normalize>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
      </Switch>
    </Normalize>
  )}/>
);
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/financefe`, I hit the render function.  The `Normalize` components is rendered.  I then try to go to `localhost:3000/financefe/test`, but the `Test` component does not get hit.  What am I missing?  Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

react-router v4 route paths must be absolute.  here's an example taken from [this article](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf), under the section named "Nested Routes":

```
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
      <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)
const Roster = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/roster' component={FullRoster}/>
    <Route path='/roster/:number' component={Player}/>
  </Switch>
)
```